# Rectangle paramtrization

Tags: integration, parametrization

> Let $\Gamma=ABCD$, where:
>
> $$A(0,0),B(a,0),C(a,\alpha),D(0,\alpha)$$
>
> $$\omega=Pdx+Qdy=e^{-x^2+y^2}\cos(2xy)dx+e^{-x^2+y^2}\sin(2xy)$$

with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and $a$ they don't say anything about it. However I have to use this to calculate:

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2}cos(2\alpha t)dt$$

But since $\Gamma$ is a closed curve then $\int_{\Gamma}\omega= 0$.
However how do I parametrize this and what is the intuition behind it?

My attempt:

when trying to parametrize I said: $\Gamma = AB\cup BC\cup CD\cup DA$

and so:

$AB:$
$$x(t) = t$$
$$y(t) = 0$$
$t\in [0,a]$

$BC:$
$$x(t)=a$$
$$y(t) = t$$
$t\in [0,\alpha ]$

$CD:$
$$x(t)=a-t$$
$$y(t)=\alpha$$
$t\in [0,a]$

$DA:$
$$x(t)=0$$
$$y(t) = \alpha -t$$

$t\in [0,\alpha]$

Now how do I construct the integral?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself actually:

Using that parametrization you get that:

$$0=\int_{\Gamma}\omega=\int_{0}^{a}e^{-t^2}dt+\int_0^{\alpha}e^{-a^2+t^2}cos(2at)dt-\int_0^ae^{-t^2+\alpha^2}cos(2\alpha t)dt$$

If we note that desired integral with $I$. We can see that from the last expression we get:

$$Ie^{\alpha^2}=\int_{0}^{a}e^{-t^2}dt+\int_0^{\alpha}e^{-a^2+t^2}cos(2at)dt$$

Letting $a\to\infty$

We get:
$$\boxed{I=\frac {\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-\alpha^2}}$$